# Eclipse : Converting a project to Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Run on server option is not displaying in eclipse .

The solution for it that i found is " check Project properties / Project Facets / Dynamic Web module" .
For this we need to unlock utility module and then check Dynamic Web Module.

But , Utility module is also necessary for Java EE Application. So how to select both Utility and Dynamic Web Module to make it Dynamic Web Project so that we can get Run On server Option.

Note : I have already copied necessary things in .project file and files in .settings folder.

**Update**

Its not a maven project. Actually utility Module is already checked in the project Facet.

The problem is that I am not getting "Run On Server"optionto run the project .to get this i need to make it a "Dynamic Web Module" .

As utility Module is already checked so i need to unlock it to check "Dynamic Web Module". Now, I cant check "Dynamic Web Module" as "utility Module" is already checked and both cant exist at same time.

If I uncheck Utility Module and check "Dynamic Web Module" then after clicking apply button I get Error "Failed in uninstalling the Utility Module".

So still left with same "utility Module" checked & "Dynamic Web Module" unchecked. 
and not got the "Run On Server" Option.

Comment: is it maven project ?

Comment: What do you mean Utility is required?  That's only required for Java Projects that you want to deploy as .jar files in the WEB-INF/lib folder *when* *you* *deploy*. It needs the ModuleCore nature to tell it how to layout the deployment.

Comment: @user2842014: Edit your question, don't post additional info as an answer.

Comment: I'm getting the `Failed in uninstalling the Utility Module` too. I'm on Eclipse Luna.